# php mutex for ram based wordpress cache in php

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to implement a cache for a high traffic wp site in php. so far ive managed to store the results to a ramfs and load them directly from the htaccess. however during peak hours there are mora than one process generatin certain page and is becoming an issue

i was thinking that a mutex would help and i was wondering if there is a better way than system("mkdir cache.mutex")

Comment: why dont you use a reverse proxy to get rid of the server load? http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy.html

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to make sure only a single process at a time is running a certain piece of code. A mutex or similar mechanism could be used for this. I myself use lockfiles to have a solution that works on many platforms and doesn't rely on a specific library only available on Linux etc.

For that, I have written a small `Lock` class. Do note that it uses some non-standard functions from my library, for instance, to get where to store temporary files etc. But you could easily change that.

```
<?php   
    class Lock
    {
        private $_owned             = false;

        private $_name              = null;
        private $_lockFile          = null;
        private $_lockFilePointer   = null;

        public function __construct($name)
        {
            $this->_name = $name;
            $this->_lockFile = PluginManager::getInstance()->getCorePlugin()->getTempDir('locks') . $name . '-' . sha1($name . PluginManager::getInstance()->getCorePlugin()->getPreference('EncryptionKey')->getValue()).'.lock';
        }

        public function __destruct()
        {
            $this->release();
        }

        /**
         * Acquires a lock
         *
         * Returns true on success and false on failure.
         * Could be told to wait (block) and if so for a max amount of seconds or return false right away.
         *
         * @param bool $wait
         * @param null $maxWaitTime
         * @return bool
         * @throws \Exception
         */
        public function acquire($wait = false, $maxWaitTime = null) {
            $this->_lockFilePointer = fopen($this->_lockFile, 'c');
            if(!$this->_lockFilePointer) {
                throw new \RuntimeException(__('Unable to create lock file', 'dliCore'));
            }

            if($wait && $maxWaitTime === null) {
                $flags = LOCK_EX;
            }
            else {
                $flags = LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB;
            }

            $startTime = time();

            while(1) {
                if (flock($this->_lockFilePointer, $flags)) {
                    $this->_owned = true;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    if($maxWaitTime === null || time() - $startTime > $maxWaitTime) {
                        fclose($this->_lockFilePointer);
                        return false;
                    }
                    sleep(1);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Releases the lock
         */
        public function release()
        {
            if($this->_owned) {
                @flock($this->_lockFilePointer, LOCK_UN);
                @fclose($this->_lockFilePointer);
                @unlink($this->_lockFile);
                $this->_owned = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

Now you can have two process that run at the same time and execute the same script

**Process 1**

```
$lock = new Lock('runExpensiveFunction');

if($lock->acquire()) {
  // Some expensive function that should only run one at a time
  runExpensiveFunction();
  $lock->release();
}
```

**Process 2**

```
$lock = new Lock('runExpensiveFunction');

// Check will be false since the lock will already be held by someone else so the function is skipped
if($lock->acquire()) {
  // Some expensive function that should only run one at a time
  runExpensiveFunction();
  $lock->release();
}
```

Another alternative would be to have the second process wait for the first one to finish instead of skipping the code.

```
$lock = new Lock('runExpensiveFunction');

// Process will now wait for the lock to become available. A max wait time can be set if needed.
if($lock->acquire(true)) {
  // Some expensive function that should only run one at a time
  runExpensiveFunction();
  $lock->release();
}
```

**Ram disk**

To limit the number of writes to your HDD/SSD with the lockfiles you could create a RAM disk to store them in.

**On Linux** you could add something like the following to `/etc/fstab`

```
tmpfs       /mnt/ramdisk tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,noexec,nodiratime,size=1024M   0 0
```

**On Windows** you can download something like [ImDisk Toolkit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit/) and create a ramdisk with that.

[image: ImDisk RamDisk Configuration Tool]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @gries, a reverse proxy is going to be a really good bang-for-the-buck way to get high performance out of a high-volume Wordpress site.  I've leveraged Varnish with quite a lot of success, though I suspect you can do so with nginx as well.